# Dinâmica defaultPage para aplicativo mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, nativescript

Bom dia/tarde/noite!

Estou desenvolvendo um APP mobile! Neste APP existe uma tela para login e uma tela principal. Eu quero que ao usuário não precise fazer o login toda vez que entre no APP, na primeira vez o app iria abrir a tela de login nas outras vezes iria abrir direto a tela principal. Passei ontem o dia todo buscando uma solução para criar uma defaultpage dinâmica.

Tentar explicar como esta meu codigo!

[image: Estrutura de arquivos do APP]
[image: Estrutura de arquivos do APP]

No arquivo app-root.xml

```
<Frame defaultPage="views/login/login-page"></Frame>
```

No arquivo app.js

```
const applicationModule = require("tns-core-modules/application");
applicationModule.run({moduleName: "app-root"});
```

Já tentei coisas como:

No arquivo app-root.xml

```
<Frame defaultPage="{{route}}" loaded="init"></Frame>
```

Em um novo arquivo app-route.js

```
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
exports.init= (args)=> {
    if(appSettings.getString("isLogin", "") == "true"){
        page.bindingContext = new observableModule.fromObject({route: "views/feed/feed-page"});
    }else {
        page.bindingContext = new observableModule.fromObject({route: "views/login/login-page"});
    }
};
```

Não obtive sucesso, tentei varias outras coisas como alterar o próprio app.js. Tentando algo do tipo
No arquivo app.js

```
const applicationModule = require("tns-core-modules/application");
let module = "app-root"
if(appSettings.getString("isLogin", "") == "true") module = "views/feed/feed-page"
applicationModule.run({moduleName: module });
```

Essa tentativa gerou o erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma boa saída para codificar essa funcionalidade!

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, Infelizmente não e uma solução bonita!

Ao inicializar o app eu direciono para uma Page intermediaria. Essa page verifica se o usuário esta logado ou não e redireciona para a Page correta.

Segue os codigos!

app-root.xml

```
<Frame id="frame" defaultPage="views/initialization/initialization-page"></Frame>
```

app.js

```
const applicationModule = require("tns-core-modules/application");
applicationModule.run({moduleName: "app-root"});
```

Neste contexto a primeira tela aberta e a tela initialization-page.xml

Segue o codigo dessa
initialization-page

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" loaded="init"></Page>
```

Em initialization-page.js

```
const frameModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");
const appSettings = require("tns-core-modules/application-settings");

let page;
exports.init = ()=> {
    if(appSettings.getString("isLogged", "") == "true") frameModule.Frame.topmost().navigate("views/feed/feed-page");
    else frameModule.Frame.topmost().navigate("views/login/login-page");
};
```

Foi esse o modo que consegui fazer funcionar, não e o melhor método, ate encontrar um melhor ficará assim!!

Quem tiver uma solução melhor, por favor me ilumine.